# Powershell, Sort a list of files by version number at the end of the filename?

Tags: powershell

How would you sort this filename list with PowerShell so they will appear in descending version order?

I only need the highest version filename.

```
Name
----
CYFS_PreK_1_0_1_10
CYFS_PreK_1_0_1_11
CYFS_PreK_1_0_1_12
CYFS_PreK_1_0_1_13
CYFS_PreK_1_0_1_14
CYFS_PreK_1_0_1_15
CYFS_PreK_1_0_1_16
CYFS_PreK_1_0_1_17
CYFS_PreK_1_0_1_18
CYFS_PreK_1_0_1_19
CYFS_PreK_1_0_1_20
CYFS_PreK_1_0_1_21
CYFS_PreK_1_0_1_22
CYFS_PreK_1_0_1_23
CYFS_PreK_1_0_1_8
CYFS_PreK_1_0_1_9
```

The following will select **"CYFS_PreK_1_0_1_9"** since it is the highest number alphabetically as there are no leading zeros in the version numbers.

```
$lastVersion = get-childitem $src |
    sort-object -descending | 
    select-object -First 1 -Property:Name
```

However, I am looking for **"CYFS_PreK_1_0_1_23"**

**UPDATE:**

If we only care about the final set of numbers, we can split the name for underscores and sort the final segment numerically.

```
Get-ChildItem $_ | 
    Sort-Object {[int] $_.Name.Split("_")[5]} -Descending |
    select-object -First 1 -Property:Name
```

This works for this set, however, if we rev to version 1_0_2_x, then it breaks again as the final 1 in 1_0_2_1 is less than 23 in 1_0_1_23.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the [Version] type to do the version sorting. This only takes the version into account (so it doesn't care about the beginning of the filename):

```
dir $_ |
    Sort-Object { 
        [Version] $(if ($_.BaseName -match "(\d+_){3}\d+") { 
                        $matches[0] -replace "_", "."
                    } 
                    else { 
                        "0.0.0.0"
                    })  
    } | select -last 1 -ExpandProperty Name
```

Comment: Nice solution. I wasn't aware of the Version type. Thanks!

Comment: The nicest thing about this solution is that the regex ignores the anything in the file name outside of the version. That allows it to be flexible.

Comment: Awesome answer, was really helpful for my sorting needs.  I thought I'd highlight the following.

[version] "0.0.0.0"

This will return an object with a major, minor, build, revision, etc. property.  You can also omit certain levels.

[version] "0.0.0", you will end up with a major, minor and build but a -1 revision.

Really handy if you are trying to figure out the newest version and increment that.

Answer (score 3):

There may be a better way, but this works:

```
Get-ChildItem $_ | 
    Sort-Object {[int]$_.Name.Split("_")[2], [int]$_.Name.Split("_")[3], [int]$_.Name.Split("_")[4], [int]$_.Name.Split("_")[5]} -Descending |
    select-object -First 1 -Property:Name
```

Comment: I appreciate that you showed how to sort by multiple conditions correctly, which I was stuck on.

Answer (score 1):

```
ls | sort -Descending { [version]($_ -replace 'CYFS_PreK_' -replace '_','.') } 


    Directory: /Users/js/foo

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
------           7/22/19  8:34 PM              3 CYFS_PreK_1_0_1_10
------           7/22/19  8:34 PM              3 CYFS_PreK_1_0_1_9
------           7/22/19  8:34 PM              3 CYFS_PreK_1_0_1_8
```